# How to display an Object containing other Objects in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, listview

I'm new at using Vue.js and I was wondering how to display this JSON object:

```
{
    "1": [
        "15-16",
        "16-17",
        "17-18",
        "18-19"
    ],
    "2": [
        "15-16",
        "16-17",
        "17-18",
        "18-19"
    ]
}
```

in a list that has this structure:

```
<div>
<h1>The key of the object...</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>The list of all the strings inside the array</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) Is this JSON data or an object? If it's JSON, you can convert it with `JSON.parse`

Comment: This Is a JSONObject

Comment: This is the only [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop object and then loop the array inside,
here is a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-leaf-nx2mq?file=/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(value, propertyName) in data" :key="propertyName">
      <h1>The key of the {{ propertyName }}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in data[propertyName]" :key="index">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        1: ["15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19"],
        2: ["15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19"],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now that I followed your example.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below approach

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
   obj:{
    "1": [
        "15-16",
        "16-17",
        "17-18",
        "18-19"
    ],
    "2": [
        "15-16",
        "16-17",
        "17-18",
        "18-19"
    ]
   }
  };
 },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Iterating the list</h1>
  <ul v-for="(item, attr) in obj" :key="attr"> Item {{attr}}
   <li v-for="(val, index) in item" :key="index">{{val}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

in vue template you can loop through an object:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(value, key) in yourObject" :key="key">
      <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in value" :key="'sub' + item">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'myComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      yourObject: {
        "1": [
          "15-16",
          "16-17",
          "17-18",
          "18-19"
        ],
        "2": [
          "15-16",
          "16-17",
          "17-18",
          "18-19"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

- you cant loop your root tag in a component so i put my loop in a `div`.
- remember to add key when you want to loop in your template. key must have a unique value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a `v-for`. It's in relation to a `for-loop` in other programming languages.

The *syntax* for this code is looking like this:

```
<div v-for="item in json" :key="item"></div>
```

Based on what you want to show a `single v-for` or a `nested v-for`.

**NOTICE:** I've named your json `json` for better understanding.

*ONE V-FOR LOOP*:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="firstLoop in json" :key="firstLoop">
    {{firstLoop}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**OUTPUT:**
{ "1": [ "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19" ], "2": [ "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19" ] }

*TWO V-FOR LOOPS*:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="firstLoop in json" :key="firstLoop">
    <div v-for="secondLoop in firstLoop" :key="secondLoop">
      {{secondLoop}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**OUTPUT:**
[ "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19" ]
[ "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19" ]

*THREE V-FOR LOOPS*:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="firstLoop in json" :key="firstLoop">
    <div v-for="secondLoop in firstLoop" :key="secondLoop">
      <div v-for="thirdLoop in secondLoop" :key="thirdLoop">
        {{thirdLoop}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**OUTPUT:**
15-16
16-17
17-18
18-19
15-16
16-17
17-18
18-19

*For understanding*: You are looping over an json or array which you will define, than you set the key (important!). You can see based on `OUTPUT` which I've written after every loop how the syntax is working and can try it out for your own.

You can also an index to your `v-for` than you have to write it like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in json" :key="index">
```

Than you can reference everything on your `index`.

Hopefully this answer helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for sharing all those informations, this is a valid answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

With Javascripts `Object.entries()` you can get the objects properties as key-value pairs that you can loop through.

So, for example if you have your object

```
const obj = {
    "1": [
        "15-16",
        "16-17",
        "17-18",
        "18-19"
    ],
    "2": [
        "15-16",
        "16-17",
        "17-18",
        "18-19"
    ]
}
```

You can iterate over it in your template by writing something like this

```
<div 
   v-for="(key, value) in Object.entries(obj)"
   :key="key"
>
   <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
   <ul>
      <li>{{ value }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the link, I'll check it out later :D